# Passing in parameter to new_path and increasing the count on a create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, controller, routes

I've recently been working with controllers and routing. Typically when I write my new and create routes, they are:

```
get '/pages/new' => 'pages#new', as: :new_page
post '/pages/ => 'pages#create'
```

and the controller actions are:

```
def new
  @page = Page.new
end

def create
  @page = Page.new(page_params)
  if @page.save
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully created page."
    redirect_to page_path(@page) 
  else
    render action: 'new'
  end 
end

private
def page_params
    params.require(:page).permit(:book_id, :text, :page_number)
end
```

So that works for new_page_path and post_pages_path.

But what if did new_page_path(book_id: @book.id)? (Also a page belongs to a book). What does this mean and how does that change my new and create methods? Also, if I were to create a new page, how would I change the count of the number of pages in my book?

Comment: Any reason you don't use the conventional `resources :pages` stuff Rails provides? As to the question(s) you should take a long at https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your models look like, but i suppose that you've got association: `has_many`.
If so, you might want to use nested resources in routes https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

```
resources :books do
  resources :pages
end
```

that gives you always:book_id in params for pages actions. You can easily create a page associated with the book than by:

```
@book = Book.find params[:book_id]
@book.pages.build(pages_params)
```

And you don't really need to handle increasing count on create, if you properly set association. `book.pages.count` will tell you the truth.